# bootstrap Data-toggle is not working with dynamically created control

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

[image: want to achive like below in the image]I am creating a dynamic table with below j query code

below is my html table in which, I will add rows with jquery code

```
<table id="DataTable" class="table">
            <thead>              
                <tr class="sticky-th">
                    <th width="2%" id="tdid2"></th>                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

below Jquery code used to add rows into html table

```
function BindTable_New(data) {
    debugger;
    $('#DataTable tbody').empty();     

        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var rows = "<tr class= 'hovered-row' > \
                                    <td width='100%'><i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg text-primary delete-icon' data-toggle='collapse' data-placement='bottom' data-original-title='C'  id = 'delicon' aria-hidden='true'></i></td></tr>";
            $('#DataTable tbody').append(rows);
        });
  
}
```

below jquery code added into document.ready to bring togle tooltip

```
 $('.delete-icon').tooltip({
        delay: 500,
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "testing",
        html: true
    }); 


    $('body').on('mouseenter', '#FiscalPeriodDataTable', function () {
       
        if ($(this).attr('data-toggle') != 'popover') {
            console.log('calling12');
            $(this).popover({
                container: 'body',
                placement: 'left',
                trigger: 'hover'
            }).popover('show');
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: no error, data-toggle is not coming

Comment: You want the `tooltip` and `popover` both on your delete icon ?

Answer (score 1):

**Update again...**

I finally get what the problem is in your code...

You just want a tooltip but you use `data-toggle="collapse"`.... so it won't work~~~~

So change it to `data-toggle="tooltip"`, add `title="what you want to show"`, finally use `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` to enable tooltip functions.

[Tooltip](http://jsfiddle.net/rtgd89zk/)

Comment: I want to call that on mouse hover in place of click

Comment: it's adding an extra div which is disturbing the table row, can we show like a tooltip

Comment: @Vikrant all sample code works and it is just guided in bootstrap official document. Miss it too much.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, its working nice in your code, but not my side , only simple title is showing, might some css conflict is there

Comment: Do I have to add any reference also to make this working on my code

Comment: Maybe you can use a plank jsfiddle to try a code playground and compare it with your code.

Comment: Thanks Li-Jyu Gao, it solved my issue, Thanks very much